# Retrieve a value from a JOIN as if it was in the base table

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have two tables, one with firstnames, and another with lastnames:

```
firstnametable
---------------------------------------------
| id | firstname |                          |
---------------------------------------------
| 1  | John      |                          |
| 2  | Pete      |                          |
---------------------------------------------
```

```
lastnametable
---------------------------------------------
| id | lastname | firstname_id | active     |
---------------------------------------------
| 1  | Dough    | 1            | 0          |
| 2  | Do       | 1            | 1          |
| 2  | Sampres  | 2            | 1          |
---------------------------------------------
```

I am looking for Query such that it would appear as if it came from a single table:

```
firstnametable
---------------------------------------------
| id | firstname | lastname     |           |
---------------------------------------------
| 1  | John      | Do           |           |
| 2  | Pete      | Sampres      |           |
---------------------------------------------
```

But it is important for me that the results are delivered in such a fashion that the prefix is also as if the results are all from the original table, ie:`firstnametable.firstname` and `firstnametable.lastname`

Is this at all possible?

My current solution is:

```
SELECT  firstnametable.id,
        firstnametable.firstname,
        CONCAT(jointable.name) as lastname
FROM firstnametable
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT      lastname
    FROM        lastnametable
    WHERE       active = 1
) as jointable ON (firstnametable.id = jointable.firstname_id)
```

But I am still missing my desired `firstnametable` prefix for the lastname column.

Comment: 'But it is important for me that the results are delivered in such a fashion that the prefix is also as if the results are all from the original table' - I don't know what you mean by this ,the table names are never reflected in the results unless code for it and your desired result doesn't show table names so please expand on this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the firstname id in the jointtable select and I don't know what the purpose of the concat is since you aren't concating anything but you haven't selected name anywhere perhaps you meant lastname. If you want to include the table name in the headers use an alias.

```
SELECT  firstnametable.id as 'firstnametable.id',
        firstnametable.firstname   as 'firstnametable.firstname',
        jointable.lastname as 'firstnametable.lastname'
FROM firstnametable
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT      firstname_id,
                     lastname
    FROM        lastnametable
    WHERE       active = 1
) as jointable ON firstnametable.id = jointable.firstname_id;

+-------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+
| firstnametable.id | firstnametable.firstname | firstnametable.lastname |
+-------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+
|                 1 | John                     | Do                      |
|                 2 | Pete                     | Sampres                 |
+-------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```